# Ionic build failed - find the line where the error occurs

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I started a new ionic project with tabs for Android platform, where I could normally build/run it. But after modifying some code in the project (just .html and .js files) I was always getting build errors. Here is the message:

```
$ ionic build android
 ✗ (node:16936) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "D:\Ionic Projects\Ofertas\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js" "D:/Ionic Projects/Ofertas"
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources FAILED


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.105 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Probably there is an error in my code. So, there is a way to find the line which has the error? Don't know how to use the --info or --debug flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week spent trying to solve this problem, find a solution. The error was caused by an image (placed at www/img/) named with non ascii characters. So I just renamed the file and everything worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when I updated node.js to version 6+. This issue is also documented at the link: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/960

Use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to downgrade Node to long-term support (LTS) version (currently v4.4.7) to resolve the issue.

Comment: The issue reported in github is different from what I exposed. The user mentioned an issue about a deprecated version of graceful-fs. It is not my problem. Also, I tried to downgrade Node and still can't build my aplication.